# how do I launch Evernote to view a notebook

Tags: ios, evernote

I'm developing an iOS application and would like to connect it with Evernote.

I've looked through the Evernote SDK and sample code, and see a `viewNoteInEvernote` method to view a note in Evernote.

But how do I view a notebook?

Specifically, I see a `ENNoteViewRequest` object. What do I need to create a `ENNotebookViewRequest`?

Thanks!

Drew

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ENSearchViewRequest object instead and pass it search grammar : notebook:"Food" .

Here is an example : https://gist.github.com/mustafa/d3c8c6938db45af0667f

Or, alternatively you can use the [findNotesMetadata](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) API to display all the notes within your app itself.